# Immediate project files synchronization for all users

Tags: eclipse, version-control, synchronization, filesystems, project-management

Me and my partners are working on a project with eclipse. Is it possible to work all together in the same project having all files in sync when someone changes something?

I was thinking having the project in a dropbox folder and everyone load it from there. Any file change will be sync with others and the project will be updated at once but ... will eclipse load the updated files at once by itself? Other problems occur when 2 persons changes a file and a conflict will occur.

In general I would like a functionality like google docs where the doc is common and everyone can see other's cursor and all together edit the file simultaneously.

Is there any way to do this with a project? Eclipse plugin maybe?

Thanks

ps. Any tag suggestions for the question will be welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Developers usually use a source control system such as Git or SVN. In these you work on your own copy of the code separately and merge the changes when they are committed to a central repository (such as github).

Eclipse has plugins for SVN, Git and several other source control systems.

I am not aware of any plugin that allow simultaneous editing of a file.

Comment: SVN and git are good but it's difficult to write code simultaneously when both want to make changes at the same file. I'm not sure how these systems handle this situations ...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty much exactly like [Git](http://git-scm.com/) what you're looking for. All you need is some kind of host (may it be a local server, Dropbox or an online repository hoster like GitHub, Bitbucket (free private repositories) or VisualStudio Online (free, amazing, but kinda slow), and you can submit, track and merge changes as you like. You can also fork your projects, track issues, and so on. There are also plugins for eclipse, as well as for most other popular IDEs or editors.
It can take a bit to get behind Git (all though it's actually pretty simple), but you and your partners will just love it, if you havn't used any SVC before.

Comment: ok but what happens when 2 people try to edit a file simultaneously?

Comment: In that case 2 separate commits will be created which can later be merged.

Comment: but this creates copies and you may not be sure which one is the correct and how to merge it. The functionality you describe is different from having the same doc and edit it on the fly by multiple users ...